# Picking questions for the Site Minicards

Tags: discussion

[Jin intends to print some site minicards](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5977153#5977153) for promoting Mathematica.SE at the WRI conference.

I suggest posting here the questions we consider appropriate, and voting on those.

Jin's guidelines are:

> The idea is that when we pass out these cards to people, the questions are so interesting that they'd be inclined to get on the computer and type in the URL to find out the answer.
>
> I prefer to have the 3 questions to cover different scopes of the site. All should have accepted answers. It'd be great if the question is in the "How to ... ?" or "What ... ?" format.

If you need to tweak a little the question title to meet the requirements, go on as far as the meaning is not distorted. And remember that both "serious and informative" and "flashy" questions are good choices.

I am posting below some questions already mentioned for this purpose in chat

**Edit**

Card sample

[image]

Comment: Many good questions below. I feel like voting for each and everyone of them, but that would be as good as not voting at all. I think everyone should restrict him/herself to voting on only half of the questions here.

Comment: Damn... I can't vote ... need a sockpuppet  ... now

Comment: @Verde Ah, I see. The trick I normally use is to add as many `[]()` as necessary. See the answer I edited below :)

Comment: Thank you for creating this post. I'll create the cards based on the highest voted answers next week!

Comment: I am trying to add a question ([this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9662/534)), but it is automatically converted to a comment ("trivial answer converted to comment"). How did you do it?

Comment: @becko Insert a few `[]()[]()` sets until you reach the minimum answer length that doesn't get converted to a comment

Comment: I wish the people who had down-voted answers had left a comment *why*...  (And I'm surprised how many do have down-votes.)

Comment: @BrettChampion I downvoted 2-3 suggestions _only_ because they didn't have an accepted answer, which was a specific requirement from Jin. It doesn't reflect on the actual question itself (I've upvoted all of them and their answers) but rather that the user didn't bother to read the instructions above. I saw a couple of comments mentioning that it had no accepted answer, so I didn't make my reasons further explicit. I don't know about the downvotes on questions with accepted answers...

Comment: @BrettChampion That is not unusual, and it is OK. In meta, downvoting means "I don't agree", and is just a subjective issue. I myself downvoted one question because, although excellent as a question per se,  I don't think it is a good match for a minicard.

Comment: @BrettChampion Suppose you think we shouldn't provide Jin with a questions list, and let himself do the choosing. Then you _should_ downvote my question here. Each question/answer in meta is like a poll.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have created the minicard designs based on the highest voted answers: "What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?" / "Using Mathematica's Graph functions to cheat at Boggle" / "How to create word clouds?" The designs have been submitted to Moo.com and the cards will be made in less than 2 weeks. Thanks!

Comment: Closed, as the voting results have been used by now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[How to create word clouds?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/how-to-create-word-clouds)

Answer (score 10):

[What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/193)

Answer (score 10):

[Using Mathematica's Graph functions to cheat at Boggle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5387/5)

Comment: Edited title: _"How can I use Mathematica's graph functions to cheat at Boggle?"_

Answer (score 9):

[How to compile effectively?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1803/193)

Comment: Perhaps `How to effectively compile Mathematica code`?

Comment: I think that `compile Mathematica code` instead of just `compile` is redundant.

Comment: @becko See for example [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6376/193)

Comment: I did not know about that. Thanks for pointing it out. But I still think that `compile` unqualified is implicitly understood as `compile Mathematica code` using the `Compile` built-in function, in the context of this site, whereas any other use of the word `compile` requires a qualifier, such as `Java compile`, as is done in that example. That is just my opinion, of course.

Answer (score 9):

[How to peel the labels from marmalade jars using Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5676/193)

Answer (score 8):

[Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)

Comment: This is a rich source. Not sure whether the title is optimal.

Comment: @Sjoerd Suggest a better one!

Comment: Where can I find good Mathematica resources?

Answer (score 6):

[File-backed lists/variables for handling large data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data)

Answer (score 6):

[How to make an inkblot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/how-to-make-an-inkblot)

Answer (score 5):

[Artistic image vectorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8507/artistic-image-vectorization)

Answer (score 3):

[How to create hedcut style images?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8716/193)

Comment: This is a great question, but is the term hedcut sufficiently familiar? I, for one, didn't know it.

Comment: This question doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: @Simon You're right. But the answers are quite good!

Answer (score 3):

[Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 1):

[Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3528/193)

Answer (score 0):

[How can one find undocumented options or option values in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/193)

Answer (score 0):

[What is the fastest way to count square-free words?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9662/534)

Answer (score -1):

[What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/219)

No accepted answer, but I think it is OK since the top answer is CW.